# XSLT разница между элементом xsl:text и текстом

Tags: xml, xslt

Для чего или в каких случаях нухно использовать элемент `<xsl:text>` в `XSLT`?

**вот пример кода**

```
     <body> 
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*)"/></h1> 
        <ul> 
          <xsl:for-each select="buch"> 
            <li> 
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/> / <xsl:value-of select="autor"/> / <xsl:value-of select="verlag"/> 
              <br/>
              <xsl:text>ISBN:</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="@isbn"></xsl:value-of> 
            </li> 
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </ul> 
      </body>
```

попробовал написать без элемента `<xsl:text>`, результат тот же.

```
<li> 
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/> / <xsl:value-of select="autor"/> / <xsl:value-of select="verlag"/> 
  <br/>
  ISBN:
  <xsl:value-of select="@isbn"></xsl:value-of> 
</li>
```

в чем же сила этого элемента?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используя `xsl:text` можно точно управлять выводом пробельных символов.

Под ваш код xsl я взял такой xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <buch isbn="1">
        <title>Title1</title>
        <autor>Autor1</autor>
        <verlag>ver1.0</verlag>
    </buch>
    <buch isbn="2">
        <title>Title2</title>
        <autor>Autor2</autor>
        <verlag>ver2.0</verlag>
    </buch>
</test>
```

Первый вариант вашего кода, с `xsl:text` даёт такой вывод:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Title1 / Autor1 / ver1.0<br />ISBN:1</li>
    <li>Title2 / Autor2 / ver2.0<br />ISBN:2</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Второй вариант выдаёт следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Title1 / Autor1 / ver1.0<br />
                        ISBN:
                        1</li>
    <li>Title2 / Autor2 / ver2.0<br />
                        ISBN:
                        2</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Как можно видеть, во втором случае значение ISBN: было скопировано вместе с пробелами перед ним, а также с переводами строки.

---

Чтобы не было недопонимания, приведу полный текст xsl-преобразования, который я использовал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*)"/>
            </h1>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="buch">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/> / <xsl:value-of select="autor"/> / <xsl:value-of select="verlag"/>
                        <br/>
                        <!--<xsl:text>ISBN:</xsl:text>-->
                        ISBN:
                        <xsl:value-of select="@isbn"></xsl:value-of>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

В таблице стилей текст можно создавать для вывода в литеральное дерево результатов с использованием элемента `<xsl:text>` или без него. Однако при использовании этого элемента можно до определенной степени контролировать пробелы, созданные таблицей стилей. Например, для улучшения читаемости таблицы стилей можно записывать каждый элемент шаблона на отдельной строке и в некоторых строках использовать отступы. В этом случае пробелы становятся составной частью правила шаблона. Это может быть как желательным, так и нежелательным эффектом преобразования.

Иногда нужно вывести пробел, чтобы разделить два значения. В этом случае можно воспользоваться элементом . Пробелы, заключенные внутри элемента `<xsl:text>`, выводятся в дерево результатов.

[Элемент `<xsl:text>` на MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256107(v=vs.120).aspx)